# rfind equivalent in R

Tags: r, indexing

I'm looking to use something like python's `rfind`, but in R.

Basically, I have a string like this: `"Black-crowned Night-Heron - Nycticorax nycticorax"`, and I'm looking to find the index of that middle hyphen ( " - " ).

The end goal is to save that index value and take a substring using the `substr()` function, with the final result being just the common name: `"Black-crowned Night-Heron"`.

Thus far I have `newvar = regexpr(" - ", specieslist, fixed = T)`, and then `substr(specieslist, 1, newvar)`, but it's returning the common names with a space after them.

So, what I want to be: `"Black-crowned Night-Heron"`

is instead: `"Black-crowned Night-Heron "`

Thanks!

Comment: `substr(*, newvar - 1)`

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks, that worked!!

Comment: `sub(" - ..*", "", input)`  -- the regular expression is space, minus, space, dot, star.

Comment: You could even do `sub("\\s+-\\s+.+$", "", txt)` to account for any number of spaces either side of the dash.

Comment: Re the end goal `strsplit(x, " - ")`?

Answer (score 1):

You can code it by hand...

```
lfind <- function(word, char){
    n <- nchar(char)  # length of string
    nw <- nchar(word)
    num_of_checks <- n*floor(nw/n) #(length of char)*(number of times you slide char)

    ind <- list()
    for (i in 1:num_of_checks){
        st <- i
        end <- i+n-1
        if (substr(word, st, end) == char){
            ind <- append(ind, i)
        }
    }
    print(ind)
}

word <- "Forastero (Nacional)"
char <- "a"
lfind(word, char)
substr(word, ind, nchar(word))
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about a built-in function, but this seems to work:

```
> str.rfind <- function(s, char) { rev(grep(char, unlist(strsplit(s, NULL)), fixed=T))[1]}
> str.rfind('This is nice.', 's')
  [1] 7
> str.rfind('This is nice.', '@')
  [1] NA
```